# How to ignore method for collection creation

Tags: mapstruct

Mapstruct used my own parameters-free method as factory for List (instead of constructor)

I tried to map some objects tree, that should built level by level. So i have a method for hardcoded root nodes and another methods, that used for mapping entities to nodes. So i have a method for generation list of root names, and abstract methods for mapping.

```
@Mapper
public abstract class TestMapper {

public List<Name> rootNames() {
    List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add(Name.build("Homer"));
    names.add(Name.build("Marge"));
    return names;
}

@Mapping(target = "name", source = "name")
public abstract Name childrenName(FullName simpson);

public abstract List<Name> childredNames(List<FullName> children);

public static class Name {
    private String name;

    public static Name build(String value) {
        Name name = new Name();
        name.setName(value);
        return name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public static class FullName {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

}

So in generated code "childrenNames" looks like
    @Override
    public List childrenNames(List children) {
        if ( children == null ) {
            return null;
        }

```
    List<Name> list = rootNames();
    for ( FullName fullName : children ) {
        list.add( simpsonName( fullName ) );
    }

    return list;
}
```

How i can mark my rootNames method as ignored for mapping?

Best regards. Alexey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the ticket https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1725 you should add the `@Named` annotation to your `rootNames()` method.
Without the annotation it will be picked up automatically as an object factory by MapStruct (see http://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#object-factories).

As soon as a method is annotated with `@Named` it will only be picked up when referenced explicitely.

```java
@org.mapstruct.Named("rootNames")
public List<Name> rootNames() {
    List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add(Name.build("Homer"));
    names.add(Name.build("Marge"));
    return names;
}
```